# Algoritmo média de dados entrados

Tags: java, algoritmo

```
package ifal2;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lista3Questao4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);


        int idade=0, contM=0, contF=0;
        double soma=0, somaaltura=0, somaM=0, percentual=0, altura;
        String sexo;

        for(int x=0; x < 3; x++) {
        System.out.println("Digite o sexo: ");
        sexo = entrada.next();
        System.out.println("Digite a idade: ");
        idade = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Digite a altura: ");
        altura = entrada.nextDouble();

        soma = soma + idade;

        if (sexo == "1") {
        somaM = somaM + idade;
        contM++;
        }
                        if (sexo == "0") {
                        somaaltura = somaaltura + altura;
                        contF++;
                        }

                somaM = somaM/contM;
                somaaltura = somaaltura/contF;

                        if (idade >= 18 && idade <= 35) {
                                percentual = percentual + idade;
                                }

        }
        System.out.println("Média da idade (geral) " + (soma/3));
        System.out.println("Média da altura (feminino) " + (somaaltura));
        System.out.println("Média da idade (masculino) " + (somaM));
        System.out.println("Percentual de pessoas com idade entre 18-35 anos: " + (percentual/3));


    }
}
```

> 4. Foi feita uma pesquisa entre os 1000 habitantes de uma região para coletar
>      os seguintes dados:
>      sexo (0-feminino, 1-masculino), idade e altura.
>      faça um algoritmo que leia as informações coletadas e mostre as seguintes informações:
>
>    a) média da idade do grupo; OK*
>
>    b) média da altura das mulheres; OK*
>
>    c) média da idade dos homens; OK*
>
>    d) percentual de pessoas com idade entre 18 e 35 anos (inclusive)

Não estou conseguindo realizar a média de idade e altura. Letra "d" também.

Coloquei 3 na estrutura de repetição só pra facilitar.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Tem vários problemas no código e isto é causado principalmente porque ele está uma completa bagunça. Eu só entendi depois de reescrever tudo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int soma = 0, somaM = 0, somaF = 0, contM = 0, contF = 0, contJ = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            System.out.println("Digite o sexo: ");
            int sexo = entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Digite a idade: ");
            int idade = entrada.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Digite a altura: ");
            int altura = entrada.nextInt();
            soma += idade;
            if (sexo == 1) {
                somaM += idade;
                contM++;
            } else if (sexo == 0) {
                somaF += altura;
                contF++;
            }
            if (idade >= 18 && idade <= 35) contJ++;
        }
        System.out.println("Média da idade (geral) " + ((double)soma / 3));
        System.out.println("Média da altura (feminino) " + ((double)somaF / contF));
        System.out.println("Média da idade (masculino) " + ((double)somaM / contM));
        System.out.println("Percentual de pessoas com idade entre 18-35 anos: " + (100 / 3 * (double)contJ));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/FlfE5f). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lgoquovo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/PeopleClassification.java).

Eu simplifiquei algumas coisas que podiam ser mais simples, entre elas deixar o sexo como numérico já que não está usando as letras comumente usadas, e preferi usar altura como centímetros. Eu poderia ter dado nomes melhores, testado o sexo para ver se está ok, acabei deixando neutro se for algo inválido.

Eu nem sei explicar tudo o que fiz de tão diferente que acabou saindo. Me lembro que tinha o cálculo da média ocorria dentro do laço, o que não faz sentido, só pode calculá-la depois de ter todas informações. Tinha erros conceituais somando coisas que não deveriam, enfim, grande parte do problema é matemático.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve contar quantas pessoas estão entre 18 e 35, e não somar as idades de quem satisfaça a condição.

Então ao invés de:

```
if (idade >= 18 && idade <= 35) {
    percentual = percentual + idade;
}
```

Você deve:

```
/* Inicializando variáveis */
int pessoasRangeIdade = 0;

/* Dentro do for */
if (idade >= 18 && idade <= 35) {
    pessoasRangeIdade++;
}

/* Após o for */
percentual = pessoasRangeIdade/3; //Sendo 3 a quantidade total de pessoas - Sugiro deixar dinâmico na entrada do programa.

System.out.println("Percentual de pessoas com idade entre 18-35 anos: " + (percentual));
```